# Why does BCF (boron carbofluoride) not exist?

Tags: molecular-structure

$\ce{BCF}$ (boron carbofluoride, or carbon borofluoride, not to be confused with another so-called BCF molecule that has nothing to do with it) should exist as a vapor molecule with the bonds $\ce{B≡C-F}$, it's simple; but it doesn't seem to exist, or I can't find any information (I just found a heavy thesis where $\ce{H2··FCB}$ —a theoretical molecule with Van Der Waals forces— is computationally studied, but it turns to be quite unstable even with the help of $\ce{H2}$).
Instead, other molecules like $\ce{C2O}$, $\ce{FBO}$, $\ce{NCF}$, vapor $\ce{BN}$, etc, do exist.

Why not $\ce{BCF}$ or $\ce{BCCl}$?

Comment: Even C=B-F would be much more viable.

Comment: @Mithoron  You are right about C=B-F, now I've read a few papers which state that computationally it is 100 - 200 kJ/mol more favorable than BCF.  Anyway even C=B-F seems to be quite unstable.  So in your opinion, as a thought experiment, if we could engineer to obtain BCF, we would just get C=B-F?  It's a sound idea.

Comment: FCB molecule wouldn't survive perhaps even single collision with another FCB, and probably even H2 - instant addition on first occasion. Your FCB would be absurdly strong Lewis acid.